# How to import ipyparallel function from user defined package, Python

Tags: python, ipython-parallel

I have a python script that contains a number of user defined functions that I have set up a as package locally.  I can run all of the functions in the input_processing.py script except for the one that I intend to run in parallel.

Here is the code that imports the package...

```
import attrition25.input_processing as attrition
```

I get this error...

```
NameError: name 'dview' is not defined
```

This is what the function looks like in input.processing.py...

```
@dview.parallel(block=True)
def get_dmat_elements(a, b, c):
    d = a + b + c
    return(d)
```

I tried sync_imports() and looked at the @interactive decorator, but I couldn't get anywhere.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't completely get the scoping, to get the function to work, I had to add this to the beginning of the input_processing.py script...

```
import ipyparallel as ipp
# Create directView Instance for Parallel Processing
c = ipp.Client()
dview = c[:] # use all engines
```

I have the same exact block of code in the Jupyter Notebook where I am testing, but that did not work.

Hopefully this helps someone out there.

Cheers!